# Не удалось найти тип или пространство имен DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#

Подключил в ссылки:
[image: 1]

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
```

Перестал выдавать ошибку, но:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Bsmessage));
```

По прежнему чем-то не доволен:
[image: 2]

Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) лежит в сборке `System.Runtime.Serialization`, а не в `System.ServiceModel.Web`.

Вы подключили не ту ссылку (не тот Reference) на первом скриншоте.